# Statistical hypothesis test for classification accuracy

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, clustering, accuracy

I just want to make sure I'm doing things right!

I created 2 algorithms that classify my data into 2 groups. 
The first one gives me an accuracy of 76.66% (sensitivity=0.76, specificity=0.78).
The second one: accuracy 81.33% (sensitivity=0.86, specificity=0.76)

So **i wanted to know if this improvement is "statistically significant".** 
I used **McNemar's test** (statistical test used on paired nominal data. It is applied to 2 × 2 contingency tables).

Is it a "good" way to proceed? 
if not which test should I choose?

Comment: Yes, a 2x2 contingency table would be appropriate to assess the null $H_0: \text{accuracy of both methods the same}$

Comment: Thank you!
What would be the null hypothesis?

Comment: The null is that the accuracy of both methods is the same.

Comment: but the test is not on the accuracy it's on the entire classification.The McNemar's test is  is applied to 2 × 2 contingency tables, true and false of the old classification and the true and false of the new classification

Comment: Ok...but you ask in the question "if this accuracy improvement" is significant. If you want to test the accuracy, the 2x2 table (1 variable = the algorithm, 1 variable = correct or not); if you want to test the over all model results, then you would need a 2x2x2 table (1 variable for algorithm, 1 variable for original data, 1 variable for classification category).

Comment: @GreggH why 2x2x2 table? Can I just use 2x2? For exemple using R:
`
algo1<-c(rep('false',20),rep('true',50))
algo2<-c(rep('false',10),rep('true',60))
table(algo1,algo2) #the contingency table algo2
algo1 false true false 10 10 true 0 50
mcnemar.test(table(algo1,algo2))` Result: `McNemar's Chi-squared test with continuity correction
data: table(algo1, algo2)
McNemar's chi-squared = 8.1, df = 1, p-value = 0.004427
` Also McNemar's test works only with 2x2 contingency tables (if i am not mistaken) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test)

Comment: You are right sorry and thank you @GreggH . I give an answer below btw